# Webpack dev VS production server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Just like we have the webpack-dev-server (only for development), I was wondering, do we also have webpack for production server, something like webpack-prod-server. This is getting very confusing

```
module.exports = {
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080', // WebpackDevServer host and port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './js/app' // Your appʼs entry point
],
output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You would run `webpack -p` and it would output a minified bundle.

You then use something like nginx or some other web server and load an html file that imports your minified JS bundle.

To skip having to edit an html file with the bundle location, you can use https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin.